# project | configuration debug | destination iphone 11 pro | sdk simulator 13.6 - react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am creating an app using react native. I updated my project from react native 0.60 to react native 0.63.2. In doing this I had to update  my cocoapods within my iOS project (shown below).

My profile file.

```js
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'


target 'Example' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example

  use_react_native!

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'


  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'RNCMaskedView', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view'

  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  pod 'react-native-slider', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider'

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth'

  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'react-native-notifications', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-notifications'

  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'Example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
   
end 

  target 'Example' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    
    
     # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
      end
    end
  end




target 'Example-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example-tvOS

end
```

When I try to run my app on an iOS emulator in Xcode I get the following errors

[image: error]

[image: error]

Can't seem to find any fix for this online.

Comment: It looks like flipper isn't installed correctly.

Comment: is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Usually I do not manually link the libraries. When we run the command `npx react-native run-ios` its done automatically. Try by running the `pod install` command

Comment: Try ‘npx react-native link’ or ‘react native link’

Comment: this didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your `Podfile` based on a one that is built with 0.63.2. Below is a working one. Adapt your node_modules directory to your project and add necessary pods to your target block.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'mobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config[:reactNativePath])

  target 'mobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'mobile-tvOS' do
  # Pods for mobile-tvOS

  target 'mobile-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Don't forget to run `pod install` again.